# KeyStore.load(InputStream stream, char[] password); How do I know the password on the client side?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I know that to load a certificate to use, I need to call `KeyStore.load(InputStream, char[]);`. How could I load the certificate on the client side if I need the password? I don't need this when connecting to Google, but I want to use Trust Managers to validate Google certificates. I also cannot make a `SSLServerSocket` and connect to it without loading a certificate.

**EDIT:** Added code:

```
package testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 443;
        String host = "google.com";

        try {

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            InputStream ksIs = new FileInputStream("securecert.certificate");
            try {
                ks.load(ksIs, "pwdpwdpwd".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                if (ksIs != null) {
                    ksIs.close();
                }
            }
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, "pwdpwdpwd".toCharArray());
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),
                    new TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager() }, null);

            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory
                    .getDefault();
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
            socket.startHandshake();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[] {};
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have to load the certificate, securecert.certificate, at the like of code ks.load(InputStream, char[]); I of course know the password, but what if I don't? Then how could I validate the certificate with a trust manager? This code simply locks. Please answer. Thanks!

Comment: Load the certificate on client side? What are you exactly doing? You have a java client and you want to connect to a webserver using certificate authentication... or you only want to validate the `https` connection validating the server certificate against your `truststore`?. Maybe with more information we can help you.

Comment: @albciff There you go!

Comment: You don't need a certificate or a KeYManager at the client unless the server asks you to send a client certificate, i.e. unless you're doing mutual authentication. If you have a client certificate it would have started life as a private keypair generated by the client user, into a KeyStore created by the client user, who therefore knows the password he used. So ask the user when you need it. Or get them all to agree on a single password and hardcode it into your application, if you think that's secure, and if they all agree. I wouldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you need a client authentication through `SSL` and you want let the user enter the password for his `keystore`. Based on your explanation I suppose that each installed client has its own `keystore` from a local path (If not the question has nonsense because if the `keystore` is always the same you don't need to pass a different password each time... however if this is the case you've to check if this client it's secure).

So to let the user enter a password you can instantiate the `keystore` in a different way instead of using `KeyStore.getInstance(InputStream, Char[])`, you can use `KeyStore.Builder.newInstance` and  `KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection` methods, and you have to create a class which implements `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler`, this class have to override `handle()` method for example using swing or awt panel to let the user introduce the password. Below I show you some sample code to guide you through this steps:

#### Load the keystore

```
import java.io.File;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class KeyStoreCallbackSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // instantiate a keystore to get the provider for specific type
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        // create the callback handler to get the password
        KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection cbhp = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new YourImplementationCallbackHander());
        // create the builder passing keystoreType, provider, keystore file, and callbackhandler
        KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("JKS", ks.getProvider(), new File("/path/YourKeyStore.jks"), cbhp);
        // create the keystore
        ks = builder.getKeyStore();

        // print the keystores alias to check if all it's load correctly
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        while(aliases.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(aliases.nextElement());
        }       
    }
}
```

#### CallbackHandler implementation

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

/**
 * PIN handler for keystores
 */
public class PinInputHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    private char[] lastPassword;

    public PinInputHandler(){}

    // implement this method to handle the callback
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (Callback cb : callbacks) {
            if (cb instanceof javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback) {
                javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback pcb = (javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback) cb;
                try {
                    this.lastPassword = // HERE YOUR SWING OR AWT OR ANOTHER WAY TO GET THE PASSWORD FROM THE CLIENT
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                pcb.setPassword(this.lastPassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more info you can check at [`KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), [`KeyStore.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.Builder.html), [`KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection.html) and [`CallbackHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html)documentation.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I appreciate this answer, it clarify my doubts about "what does 'prompt' here means, does it prompts automatically a dialog for inputting password and so on?" (obviously, it doesn't and it's left for us to implement the Swing/AWT part. ).

Comment: @FaithReaper thanks for your feedback, I left this part because it's very concrete depends on the implementation... a `prompt` it's not mandatory maybe some one for example read the password from a property file.